# Why are no CLR exceptions being reported in Dynamics AX?

Tags: exception, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

When an exception ocurrs in my .NET code, the X++ code just stops executing and drops out. It doesn't display any error message at all, it simply stops working.

Why is this? Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to solve that:

```
System.Exception                        e; // declare
```

;

```
try
{
       ... code that can throw clr error
}
catch (Exception::CLRError)
{
       e = CLRInterop::getLastException();

       while( e )
       {
           info( e.get_Message() );
           e = e.get_InnerException();
       }
}
```

Also read more here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/07/22/working-with-clr-exceptions-in-dynamics-ax-x-code.aspx

Comment: I would hate to have to put exception handling around every CLR call we make. Isn't there a setting that so that it will just put the error into the info/error log or something?

Comment: Well, that is not all you need to do if you add code with dependency to CLR. You also need to assert CLR Interop permission, if you want to follow best practice. 
I guess you could modify the class Info, and method add(), but that would be bad practice. 
Will be interesting to see how this is solved in AX2012. As for AX 2009, there are guidelines for best practice, and when you need code dependent on CLR you should make sure error handling is done properly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677495.aspx